# C# PInvoke Finding the window handle of a child window from a known window

Tags: c#, pinvoke

I am currently attempting to get some text from a child window using `SendMessage` via C# PInvoke. However, my previous attempts to hardcore the window handle failed as the value changes upon the startup of the application. Is there a way to reliably get the window handle of this child window? **Winspector** spy shows that the class name of this window is `RichEdit20W`. My current code is as follows:

```
IntPtr hWnd= (IntPtr) 0xA0E88; // Hardcode window handle


int txtlen = SendMessage(hWnd, WM_GETTEXTLENGTH, 20, null);
StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder(txtlen);
int RetVal = SendMessage(hWnd, WM_GETTEXT, text.Capacity, text);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using the Managed Windows API to enumerate all descendant windows of the window.

```
            var descendantwindows = childWindows[0].AllDescendantWindows; // Get all descendant windows of CMainWindow

        for (int i = 0; i<descendantwindows.Length; i++)
        {
            if (descendantwindows[i].ClassName == "RichEdit20W")
                childHandle = descendantwindows[i].HWnd;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can get the top-level window (the one with the title bar), you can use [FindWindowEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633500%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to recurse through the children.  This lets you specify the text of the window (use null since you don't know it), and/or the class (which you know).

http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.findwindowex

Answer (score 0):

You can PInvoke the API `[FindWindow][1]` in order to have the top level window, or maybe better, if you know the process name, by using:

```
Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("yourprocessname");

foreach (Process p in processes)

{

    IntPtr pFoundWindow = p.MainWindowHandle;

    // Do something with the handle...

    //

}
```

Notice there is more entries because there can be potentially more process instance running at the same time. Then you need some strategy to lookup the top level children to point exactly the window you are looking for.